# Access next item in for loop bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to loop through my file and grab the lines in groups of 2. Every data entry in the file contains a header line and then the following line has the data.

I am trying to: Loop through the file, grab every two lines and manipulate them. My current problem is that I am trying to echo the next line in the loop. So every time I hit a header row, it will print the data line (next line) with it.

```
out="$(cat $1)" #file
file=${out}

iter=0
for line in $file;
do
    if [ $((iter%2)) -eq 0 ];
    then
            #this will be true when it hits a header
            echo $line
            # I need to echo the next line here
    fi
    echo "space"
    iter=$((iter+1))

done
```

Here is an example of a possible input file:

```
>fc11ba964421kjniwefkniojhsdeddb4_runid=65bedc43sdfsdfsdfsd76b7303_read=42_ch=459_start_time=2017-11-01T21:10:05Z <br>
TGAGCTATTATTATCGGCGACTATCTATCTACGACGACTCTAGCTACGACTATCGACTCGACTACSAGCTACTACGTACCGATC
>fd38df1sd6sdf9867345uh43tr8199_runid=65be1fasdfsdfgdsfg4376b7303_read=60_ch=424_start_time=2017-11-01T21:10:06Z <br>
TGAGCTATTATTATCGGCGACTATCTATCTACGACGACTCTAGCTACGACTATCGACTCGACTACSAGCTACTACGTACCGATC
>1d03jknsdfnjhdsf78sd89ds89cc17d_runid=65bedsdfsdfsdf03_read=24_ch=439_start_time=201711-01T21:09:43Z <br>
TGAGCTATTATTATCGGCGACTATCTATCTACGACGACTCTAGCTACGACTATCGACTCGACTACSAGCTACTACGTACCGATC
```

header lines start with `>` and data is the lines containing `TGACATC`

## EDIT:

For those asking about the output, based on the original question, I am trying to access the header and data together. Each header and matching data will be processed 6 times. The end goal is to have each header and data pair:

>fc11ba964421kjniwe (original header) 
GATATCTAGCTACTACTAT (original data)

translate to:

>F1_fc11ba964421kjniwe 
ASNASDKLNASDHGASKNHDLK
>F2_fc11ba964421kjniwe
ASHGASKNHDLKNASDKLNASD
>F3_fc11ba964421kjniwe
KNHDLKNASDKLNASDASHGAS
>R1_fc11ba964421kjniwe
ASHGLKNASDKLNASDASKNHD
>R2_fc11ba964421kjniwe
AKNASDKLNASDSHGASKNHDL 
>R3_fc11ba964421kjniwe 
SKNHDLKNASDKASHGALNASD

and then the next header and data entry would generate another 6 lines

Comment: What is the output you need? How do you want to process them?

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001); a `for` loop is the wrong way to iterate over the contents of a file line-by-line.

Comment: @Nic3500: one generally develops a set of programming tools that get recycled from project to project, whether they are software libraries or mental processes for visualizing problems. While a `for` loop may work in certain situations, I'm pretty sure there is no case where `for` provides a *superior* mechanism for reading file contents to `while`. If you have evidence to the contrary, please share, I would love to expand my understanding.

Comment: @ghoti: makes sense, thanks.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect what my end goal is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your records each consist of exactly 2 lines, use the `read` command twice on each iteration of the `while` loop.

```
while IFS= read -r line1; IFS= read -r line2; do
    ...
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Does `IFS` need to be set if you're only reading into a single variable?

Comment: In general, yes. Without `IFS=`, any leading or trailing IFS whitespace will be stripped. If you have *no* variable, such as when you rely on the `bash` default `REPLY`, then you can omit `IFS`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for line in $file` notation cannot work; in bash, the text after `in` is a series of values, not an input file. What you're probably looking for is a `while read` loop that takes the file as standard input. Something like this:

```
while read -r header; do

  # We should be starting with a header.
  if [[ $header != >* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: corrupt header: $header" >&2
    break
  fi

  # read the next line...
  read -r data

  printf '%s\n' "$data" >> data.out

done < "$file"
```

I don't know what output you're looking for, so I just made something up. This loop enforces header position with the `if` statement, and prints data lines to an output file.

Of course, if you don't want this enforcement, you could simply:

```
grep -v '^>' "$file"
```

to return lines which are not headers.